# how to translate countries output from wp database?

Tags: wp-query, wpdb, translation

i have a list of countries in french stored in my database (wp_country). i use the code above to retrieve all the countries witth this ecohing `echo '"' . $country['name_country'] . '",';` it outputs countries in this format `"France",` `"Afrique du sud",` `"italie",` and so. the reason i output countries between brackets followed by comma, is that i want theme inpusted in a javascript autocomplete variable : `var availableCountries = [//countries list from wp_country ?> ]`.

My probleme is how to translate the outputed countries with the translate functions `__()` or `_e()`

```
<?php

global $wpdb;  

    $sql_countries = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT id, name_country  FROM country ORDER            BY name_country ASC");
    $result_countries = mysql_query($sql_countries); 

    while($country = mysql_fetch_array($result_countries)) { 

        echo '"' . $country['name_country'] . '",'; 
    } 


            ?>
```

thank you

Answer (score 1):

you need to have the actual translations somewhere in a .mo file.  for your plugin / theme.

1) when you setup the codes, you can also "mark them for translation"
http://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers#Marking_Strings_for_Translation

2) create the translations for the languages somehow - various tools.  eg this one:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/codestyling-localization/

3) in your plugin  must tell wp to load the translation 'domain'
http://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers#Choosing_and_loading_a_domain

4) then to get the translation reference the domain in the call

__('String', 'your_domain')

Note:
There are various 'country' or multi language plugins that may have country translations already - try searching the wp plugins db.  You could 'copy' their .mo and .po files if you did not want their plugin active. (you'd use their domain if you were not copying).